# Web browser hooked pulseaudio sound, how to release?

Tags: audio, chrome, pulseaudio

It seems that Chrome (and its Flash component) has grabbed all the audio on the machine for itself, leaving no sound for any other applications.  I am running KDE with PulseAudio.  Is there a way in the myriad different applications* that handle sound on Linux to convince Chrome to give up its death grip on audio so that other applications can get a chance to make noise?

*- Looked at alsamixer, kmixer and Phonon (KDE multimedia configurer).  Settings are a-ok, no indication that one application has hogged the audio device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the ALSA driver for PulseAudio then it will redirect ALSA audio through PulseAudio instead of hogging the ALSA device directly.

Comment: This site rocks!  The only question is how does one install the driver?  A search shows that if your system installs the driver, you can add it with a stanza in /etc/asound.conf.  Is this correct?

Comment: I just do `yum install alsa-plugins-pulseaudio`, no config required here.

Comment: I'm looking at Ubuntu, which includes the drivers with another package.  Arch is like RedHat, in that it has a separate package that autoconfigures the conf file.

Comment: I accept the answer on the basis that it works on RedHat and clones, though not Ubuntu.